# Obtener datos del dataframe según una condición

Tags: python, pandas

Realmente este post no consiste en una duda de un problema en mi código de programación, si no que me gustaría entender la diferencia (si la hubiera) entre emplear,

```
val = df[df['sepal length (cm)'] > 4.5]
```

o mediante `loc`,

```
val = df.loc[df['sepal length (cm)'] > 4.5]
```

pues el resultado es el mismo. ¿Hay casos mejores para emplear una opción u otra?

Para el ejemplo he usado el dataset de iris,

```
import sklearn.datasets
iris = sklearn.datasets.load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
```

Gracias

Comment: cuando usas `.loc` podes leer y escribir, por ejemplo : `df.loc[df['sepal length (cm)'] > 4.5,'sepal length (cm)]='hola' `. Sin embargo si lo haces sin el `.loc` no te va a dejar

Answer (score 2):

## Eficiencia

Las dos operaciones no solo son compatibles en este caso sino que a nivel de eficiencia también parece que no haya mayores diferencias:

```
# Usando []
%timeit val = df[df['sepal length (cm)'] > 4.5]
1.09 ms ± 21 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# Usando .loc
%timeit val = df.loc[df['sepal length (cm)'] > 4.5]
1.08 ms ± 20.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

## Usos

Programar de forma explicita como norma es siempre la mejor opción. Si usamos la opcion `df.loc[]` siempre sabemos que nos estamos refiriendo a filas, mientras que df[] es ambiguo en cuanto a referirse a filas o columnas. Por ejemplo:

```
# Dataframe con columnas e indices del mimsmo nombre
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]], columns = ['a', 'b'], index = ['a','b']);df
    a   b
a   1   2
b   3   4

df['a']
a    1
b    3
Name: a, dtype: int64

df.loc['a']
a    1
b    2
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Si te fijas, en la primera llamada `df['a']` el output que nos da es la **columna** `a`, mientras que `df.loc['a']` nos devuelve la **fila** `a`.
Si bien es cierto que directamente llamar a las columnas y a los indices de la misma manera ya me parece un crimen, como buena practica insisto que hacer la llamada de forma explicita siempre es aconsejable.

Por otro lado, en tu caso no estas usando una llamada a una columna como el ejemplo que te he puesto, sino aplicando una mascara booleana. Es decir, le estas diciendo al dataframe que te devuelva las filas en las que tu mascara es positiva (recordemos que `df['sepal length (cm)'] > 4.5` nos devuelve una lista de booleanos tal que asi: `[True, False, True, ...]`). Esto te puede generar problemas si alguna de tus columnas tiene nombre de booleano `df = pd.DataFrame({True:[0,1],False:[2,3]})`.

Ademas, `df.iloc[]` se puede usar para [acceder a multi-indice y para modificar valores](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) (cosa que `df[]` no te permite. )

Si el idioma no te es impedimento, te sugiero que le eches un vistazo a [este articulo](https://medium.com/dunder-data/selecting-subsets-of-data-in-pandas-6fcd0170be9c) donde encontraras una buena explicacion de los usos de `[]`, `.loc` y `.iloc`.